# What is the best way to search through an array to return the key of a sub value

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm trying to filter an array (derived from a json object), so as to return the array key based on the value. I'm not sure if array search `$key = array_search($value, $array);` is the best way to do this (I can't make it work), and I think there must be a better way.

So far I've got this, but it isn't working. Grateful for any help!

```
    public function getBedroomData(array $data,$num_beds = null,$type) {

    $data = (array) $data;

    if($num_beds > 0) {
        $searchstring = "avg_".$num_beds."bed_property_".$type."_monthly";
        } else {
        $searchstring = "avg_property_".$type."_monthly";
        }

        $avg_string = array_search($data, $searchstring);
    return $avg_string;             
    }
```

The array consists of average property prices taken from the nestoria api as follows:
http://api.nestoria.co.uk/api?country=uk&pretty=1&action=metadata&place_name=Clapham&price_type=fixed&encoding=json

This returns a long json object. My problem is that the data isn't consistent - and I'm looking for the quickest (run time) way to do the following:

```
            $data['response']['metadata']['0'] //= data to return, [0] unknown
            $data['response']['metadata']['0']['metadata_name'] = "avg_1bed_property_rent_monthly" //= string I know!
            $data['response']['metadata']['1'] //= data to return, [1] unknown
            $data['response']['metadata']['1']['metadata_name'] = "avg_1bed_property_buy_monthly" //= string I know!
            $data['response']['metadata']['2'] = //= data to return, [2] unknown
            $data['response']['metadata']['2']['metadata_name'] = "avg_2bed_property_buy_monthly" //= string I know!
            .....
            .....
            .....
            $data['response']['metadata']['10'] = avg_property_rent_monthly
            $data['response']['metadata']['11'] = avg_property_buy_monthly
            $data['response']['metadata'][most_recent_month] = the month reference for getting the data from each metadata list..
```

It isn't possible to filter the initial search query by number of bedrooms as far as I can work out. So, I've just been array slicing the output to get the information I've needed if bedrooms are selected, but as the data isn't consistent this often fails.

Comment: what happens in the end? so the desired output is returning the values inside `['data']` according to the parameters given?

Comment: So I want to print_r($data['response']['metadata']['?']['avg_values']) based on $data['response']['metadata']['?']['metadata_name'] = "known string"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To search inside that particular json response from nestoria, a simple foreach loop can be used. First off, of course call the json data that you need. Then, extract the whole data, the the next step if pretty straightforward. Consider this example:

```
$url = 'http://api.nestoria.co.uk/api?country=uk&pretty=1&action=metadata&place_name=Clapham&price_type=fixed&encoding=json';
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($contents, true);
$metadata = $data['response']['metadata'];

// dummy values
$num_beds = 1; // null or 0 or greater than 0
$type = 'buy'; // buy or rent

function getBedroomData($metadata, $num_beds = null, $type) {
    $data = array();

    $searchstring = (!$num_beds) ? "avg_property_".$type."_monthly" : "avg_".$num_beds."bed_property_".$type."_monthly";
    $data['metadata_name'] = $searchstring;
    $data['data'] = null;

    foreach($metadata as $key => $value) {
        if($value['metadata_name'] == $searchstring) {
            $raw_data = $value['data']; // main data

            // average price and data points
            $avg_price = 0;
            $data_points = 0;
            foreach($raw_data as $index => $element) {
                $avg_price += $element['avg_price'];
                $data_points += $element['datapoints'];
            }
            $data_count = count($raw_data);
            $price_average = $avg_price / $data_count;
            $data_points_average = $data_points / $data_count;

            $data['data'][] = array(
                'average_price' => $price_average,
                'average_datapoints' => $data_points_average,
                'data' => $raw_data,
            );
        }
    }

    return $data;
}

$final = getBedroomData($metadata, $num_beds, $type);

print_r($final);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The search part is useful. The averageprice is already set in the data so the foreach data_count isn't necessary (I just return 'most_recent_month').

Comment: @Simeon if you want to add the most recent month, you can just use `'most_recent_month' => end($value['data']),` inside the `$data`. good day